# Is there any solution regarding to PyQt library doesn't work in Mac OS Big Sur?

Tags: python, pyqt

I've done some project using PyQt library for my class assignmnet.
And I need to check my application working before I submit it.

Today, 3 hours ago I updated my Mac book OS to Big Sur.
And I found out that PyQt library doesn't work. It doesn't show any GUI.

Are there someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Same issue on Big Sur with Python 3.9 and PyQt 5.15.1, GUI does not show up.

Answer (score 20):

Adding `os.environ['QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER'] = '1'` fixes the issue on PyQT 5.15.1 ([credits](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/pyqt5-and-big-sur.2260773/post-29243620))

Comment: PyQt5 5.15.2 was released on Nov 24 and it supposedly integrates this fix. Can anyone running macOS Big Sur confirm that PyQt 5.15.2 works out of the box?

Comment: @cbrnr yes, PyQt 5.15.2 works fine without setting environment variable

Answer (score 6):

Rolling back to PyQt5==5.13.0 fixed the issue for me!
you should uninstall PyQt5 and then install it using
pip install PyQt5==5.13.0

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to [this](https://twitter.com/lapcatsoftware/status/1326990296412991489).

If it is, then disconnecting from the internet would fix it.
As would redirecting `ocsp.apple.com` to 0.0.0.0 in `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

Related to this, after upgrading to BigSur my app stopped launching its window...I am using the official Qt supported binding PySide2/shiboken2

Upgrading from PySide2 5.12 to 5.15 fixed the issue.

Steps:

1. Remove PySide2/shiboken2

   `pip3 uninstall PySide2`

   `pip3 uninstall shiboken2`
2. Reinstall

   `pip3 install PySide2`