# Pyinstaller on MacOS BigSur cannot build basic PyQt5 app

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to build a very basic app that uses PyQt5 on Big Sur.

Using the latest dev version of pyinstaller I build the app without errors but, when I launch it, it crashes immediately after starting.
Launching the exec, I get segmentation fault right after `app = QApplication(sys.argv)`.

Here's my configuration:

```
37 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.0.dev0
37 INFO: Python: 3.9.4
46 INFO: Platform: macOS-11.2.3-x86_64-i386-64bit
```

My code, launched with `python main.py` works. It's also not a problem of external files used by the app because it crashes way before using them.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

DEBUG = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if DEBUG:
        if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            print("Running in a Pyinstaller bundle.")
        else:
            print("Running in a normal Python process.")

        for a in sys.argv:
            print("sys.argv[]: {}".format(a))
        print(sys.executable)
        print(os.getcwd())

    if DEBUG:
        print("THIS RUNS")
    app = QApplication([])
    if DEBUG:
        print("THIS DOESN'T")
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 450)
    win.setFixedSize(300, 450)

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The pyinstaller command I use is:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --log-level=ERROR \
    --clean \
    --onefile \
    --windowed \
    --name Blabla \
    --debug all \
    --paths ~/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ \
    --paths ~/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/venv2/ \
    --paths ~/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/ \
    --hidden-import PyQt5 \
    --hidden-import PyQt5.sip \
    --hidden-import PyQt5.QtWidgets \
    --hidden-import PyQt5.QtGui \
    --hidden-import PyQt5.QtCore \
    main.py
```

Ideas?

Here's what I get in the terminal when I launch the executable:

```
(venv2) ste@ste FotoPDF % ./FotoPDF
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import 'posix' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
import 'time' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
# zipimport: found 147 names in '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import codecs # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/codecs.pyc
import encodings.aliases # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/encodings/aliases.pyc
import encodings # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/encodings/__init__.pyc
import encodings.utf_8 # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/encodings/utf_8.pyc
import encodings.ascii # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/encodings/ascii.pyc
import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import encodings.latin_1 # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/encodings/latin_1.pyc
import '_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import abc # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/abc.pyc
import io # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/io.pyc
# extension module '_struct' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module '_struct' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import '_struct' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc30892c670>
# extension module 'zlib' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module 'zlib' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import 'zlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc3089c7100>
# PyInstaller: FrozenImporter(/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/FotoPDF?60397)
import os # PyInstaller PYZ
import stat # PyInstaller PYZ
import '_stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'stat' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
# _collections_abc not found in PYZ
import _collections_abc # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/_collections_abc.pyc
import posixpath # PyInstaller PYZ
import genericpath # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'genericpath' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'posixpath' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'os' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import ctypes # PyInstaller PYZ
# types not found in PYZ
import types # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/types.pyc
# _ctypes not found in PYZ
# extension module '_ctypes' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module '_ctypes' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import '_ctypes' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308b37d60>
import ctypes._endian # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'ctypes._endian' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'ctypes' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
# ctypes.macholib not found in PYZ
# re not found in PYZ
# enum not found in PYZ
import enum # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/enum.pyc
# sre_compile not found in PYZ
import '_sre' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# sre_parse not found in PYZ
# sre_constants not found in PYZ
import sre_constants # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/sre_constants.pyc
import sre_parse # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/sre_parse.pyc
import sre_compile # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/sre_compile.pyc
# functools not found in PYZ
# collections not found in PYZ
# heapq not found in PYZ
# _heapq not found in PYZ
# extension module '_heapq' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module '_heapq' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import '_heapq' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308bbefa0>
import heapq # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/heapq.pyc
import 'itertools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# keyword not found in PYZ
import keyword # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/keyword.pyc
# operator not found in PYZ
import '_operator' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import operator # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/operator.pyc
# reprlib not found in PYZ
import reprlib # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/reprlib.pyc
import '_collections' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import collections # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/collections/__init__.pyc
import '_functools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import functools # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/functools.pyc
import '_locale' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# copyreg not found in PYZ
import copyreg # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/copyreg.pyc
import re # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/re.pyc
import multiprocessing # PyInstaller PYZ
import multiprocessing.context # PyInstaller PYZ
import threading # PyInstaller PYZ
# _weakrefset not found in PYZ
import _weakrefset # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/_weakrefset.pyc
import 'threading' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import multiprocessing.process # PyInstaller PYZ
import signal # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'signal' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'multiprocessing.process' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import multiprocessing.reduction # PyInstaller PYZ
import pickle # PyInstaller PYZ
import _compat_pickle # PyInstaller PYZ
import '_compat_pickle' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
# _pickle not found in PYZ
# extension module '_pickle' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module '_pickle' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import '_pickle' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308c985b0>
# org not found in PYZ
import 'pickle' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import socket # PyInstaller PYZ
# _socket not found in PYZ
# extension module '_socket' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module '_socket' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import '_socket' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308cbb2e0>
import selectors # PyInstaller PYZ
# collections.abc not found in PYZ
import collections.abc # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/collections/abc.pyc
# math not found in PYZ
# extension module 'math' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/math.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module 'math' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/math.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import 'math' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308cc6940>
# select not found in PYZ
# extension module 'select' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/select.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module 'select' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/select.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import 'select' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308cc69d0>
import 'selectors' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'errno' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# array not found in PYZ
# extension module 'array' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/array.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module 'array' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/array.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import 'array' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308cd3640>
import 'socket' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'multiprocessing.reduction' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'multiprocessing.context' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'multiprocessing' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import multiprocessing.spawn # PyInstaller PYZ
import runpy # PyInstaller PYZ
import importlib # PyInstaller PYZ
# warnings not found in PYZ
import warnings # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/warnings.pyc
import 'importlib' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import importlib.machinery # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'importlib.machinery' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import importlib.util # PyInstaller PYZ
import importlib.abc # PyInstaller PYZ
import typing # PyInstaller PYZ
import contextlib # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'contextlib' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'typing' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'importlib.abc' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'importlib.util' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import pkgutil # PyInstaller PYZ
# weakref not found in PYZ
import weakref # loaded from Zip /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/base_library.zip/weakref.pyc
import 'pkgutil' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'runpy' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import multiprocessing.util # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'atexit' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import subprocess # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'pwd' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# grp not found in PYZ
# extension module 'grp' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module 'grp' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import 'grp' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308ea4940>
# msvcrt not found in PYZ
# _posixsubprocess not found in PYZ
# extension module '_posixsubprocess' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module '_posixsubprocess' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import '_posixsubprocess' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308ea4a30>
import 'subprocess' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'multiprocessing.util' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import 'multiprocessing.spawn' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import multiprocessing.popen_fork # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'multiprocessing.popen_fork' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import multiprocessing.popen_spawn_posix # PyInstaller PYZ
import 'multiprocessing.popen_spawn_posix' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
import PyQt5 # PyInstaller PYZ
# possible namespace for /Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/PyQt5
import 'PyQt5' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7fc3089c7a30>
# PyQt5.QtWidgets not found in PYZ
# PyQt5.sip not found in PYZ
# extension module 'PyQt5.sip' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/PyQt5/sip.cpython-39-darwin.so'
# extension module 'PyQt5.sip' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/PyQt5/sip.cpython-39-darwin.so'
import 'PyQt5.sip' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308ea4eb0>
# PyQt5.QtCore not found in PYZ
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtCore' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so'
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtCore' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so'
import 'PyQt5.QtCore' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308ebb100>
# PyQt5.QtGui not found in PYZ
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtGui' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/PyQt5/QtGui.abi3.so'
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtGui' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/PyQt5/QtGui.abi3.so'
import 'PyQt5.QtGui' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc30a8236a0>
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' loaded from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so'
# extension module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' executed from '/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so'
import 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc308ea4c40>
Running in a Pyinstaller bundle.
sys.argv[]: ./FotoPDF
/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF/FotoPDF
/Users/ste/PycharmProjects/FotoPDF/dist/FotoPDF
THIS RUNS
zsh: segmentation fault  ./FotoPDF
```

Comment: remove ` --onefile` and execute: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 your_executable` and show the log

Comment: Do you mean I should export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 ?
I've done it, then in the same terminal run my executable but I can't see any difference in the output. I edited my question to add it.

Comment: Did you rebuild the executable without the `--onefile` option? What happens is that Qt needs plugins but when using that option it cannot find it.

Comment: I did. The one I copied in the question is the output when I run the executable created without the --onefile option.

Comment: I got it to bundle and run. All I did was this: ```pyinstaller --clean --onedir --paths "./\venv\Lib\Site-Packages" --distpath "C:\Python\Scripts\output" --noconfirm stratch.py``` Did you make sure that your virtual environment was activated? I can give a more detailed answer if you wish, but our circumstances are a little different. I'm using windows and python 3.8.3.

Comment: @stef Recommendation: Do not use recent versions of python since pyinstaller has several bugs that it takes time to resolve. Use python 3.6 and virtualenvs

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc. I'm having some issues using an older python version with pyenv but I also think this is the only way forward. Pyinstaller and BigSur don't appear to work nicely together, yet.

Comment: I tried with Python 3.6.5 (that took me a while to install on BigSur) and the result is exactly the same. I guess I need to wait for Pyinstaller to be stable on Big Sur.

Comment: Does the program work if you run it without pyinstaller? [This guy got a segmentation fault while running matplotlib on big sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841082/segmentation-fault-11-python-after-upgrading-to-os-big-sur)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a second assuming it's not Pyinstaller's fault.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841082/segmentation-fault-11-python-after-upgrading-to-os-big-sur) post matplotlib refused to work after the BigSur update until reinstalled.

And PyQt5 didn't show any GUI in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818879/is-there-any-solution-regarding-to-pyqt-library-doesnt-work-in-mac-os-big-sur) post after the BigSur update.

The if it's a problem with PyQt then the fix should be uninstalling and reinstalling PyQt5==5.15.2 with

```
pip uninstall PyQt5
pip install PyQt5== 5.15.2
```

and then setting

```
os.environ['QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER'] = '1'
```

a user also said rolling back to `PyQt5==5.12.0` solved his issue so maybe try that.
If the issue is with PyQt5 you can also switch to [PySide2](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/) which is another binding for Qt5

Incase the issue lies with PyInstaller you can look at the alternatives.

Python 3.5+ comes with zip support via zipapp, more about that [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0441/#a-new-python-zip-application-extension) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html), which lets you archive your python program into a single `.pyz` using the command

```
python -m zipapp myapp -m "myapp:main"
```

This command runs the main function from the module myapp when the archive is launched. Which can be simply run by-

```
python myapp.pyz
```

There's also [py2app](https://pypi.org/project/py2app/) which is like pyinstaller but specific to macOS.

Comment: I finally managed to build a working app wiit with pyinstaller using PySide2 instead of PyQt5 on Python 3.6.5.
Using an older version of PyQt5 did not work.
I was already able to build a working with py2app but the size of the executable was way bigger, around 160MB vs. 43MB with Pyinstaller.